# Integer operator in tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

And I have got this figure:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering                                             
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=200pt,axis x line=middle, axis y line=center, ylabel={$\frac{{\delta x}_j}{{\Delta x}_j}$},xlabel={$n$},xmin=0,xmax=6,ymin=0,ymax=1.5]
            \addplot+[mark=none,smooth] (\x,{1/(2^(\x))});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Effect of the parameter $n$ on the particle nodes scaling}
    \label{n_influence}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that I don't want this function to be plotted for the real numbers, but I would like to plot the integer part of it. Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

[image: exponential]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering                                             
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=200pt,axis x line=middle, axis y line=center,
                     ylabel={$\frac{{\delta x}_j}{{\Delta x}_j}$},
                     xlabel={$n$},xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6},xmin=0,xmax=7,ymin=0,ymax=1.5]
            \addplot+[only marks,domain=0:6,samples=7] (\x,{1/(2^(\x))});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Effect of the parameter $n$ on the particle nodes scaling}
    \label{n_influence}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```